# Does Alpine no longer work with Gmail IMAP?

Tags: gmail, alpine-linux

I'm trying to setup alpine (formerly PINE) on OSX and GMAIL keeps bouncing my login attempts by saying alpine is not a secure client / to use the web client instead.

I'm not using 2FA (so no app passwords) - so has anyone gotten alpine & gmail to cooperate recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Gmail you need to enable the setting at:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

These apps are no less secure, see:

http://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-FAQ.html#I9

(edit): Accounts with two-step verification don't allow the 'less secure' setting. Use app specific passwords instead. See separate answer for alpine configuration under this scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (August 2018) google generates app-specific passwords for your smtp client needs. (edit: I missed OP reference to two-factor authorization, so this answer while awesome is a little off topic). My experience configuring alpine 2.21 installed through home-brew was pretty painless.

Visit [your google account settings](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) and generate a password. In alpine use that password with a viable configuration, for example at the main menu type S, C (setup, configure), `smtp-server: smtp.gmail.com:587/tls/user=example@gmail.com`.

When you send a message you'll use the app-specific password instead of your general account password. Google instructions tell you not to write it down, but in alpine you'll use it for sending and receiving separately.

Also: Alpine may work to save passwords insecurely on your local machine if you `touch ~/.alpine-passfile` and then persist through confirmations, failures and repetition. From research I understand that you can compile alpine with keychain support but I haven't gone down that route.

Comment: ten million points for explaining about the app specific password.  Much as I love MFA, sometimes you want a work-around...Thanks.